# Pyspark - Glue 3.0 issue, upgrading of Spark 3.0 : reading dates before 1582-10-15 or timestamps before 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue3.0

After upgrading to `Glue 3.0` I got the following error when handling **rdd** objects

> An error occurred while calling o926.javaToPython. You may get a
> different result due to the upgrading of Spark 3.0: reading dates
> before 1582-10-15 or timestamps before 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z from
> Parquet files can be ambiguous, as the files may be written by Spark
> 2.x or legacy versions of Hive, which uses a legacy hybrid calendar that is different from Spark 3.0+'s Proleptic Gregorian calendar. See
> more details in SPARK-31404. You can set
> spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead to 'LEGACY' to
> rebase the datetime values w.r.t. the calendar difference during
> reading. Or set spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead to
> 'CORRECTED' to read the datetime values as it is.

I've already added the config mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/migrating-version-30.html#migrating-version-30-from-20)

`--conf spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead=CORRECTED --conf spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite=CORRECTED --conf spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead=CORRECTED`

this is really a blocking issue that prevents to run the Glue jobs !

Note: locally I'm using `pyspark3.1.2`, for the same data it works with no problem

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue by following the [aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/migrating-version-30.html#migrating-version-30-from-20), since general Glue [recommendation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html) is that we should not setup and use --conf parameter as it is used internally. My solution involved following:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
conf = SparkConf()

conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
```

The problem I faced using Mauricio's answer was that `sc.stop()` actually stops the execution on spark context using Glue 3.0, and disrupts the stream of data I was ingesting from the data source (RDS in my case).

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this. Default below:

```
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
```

Add additional spark configurations

```
conf = sc.getConf()
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
sc.stop()
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
```

... your code

Answer (score 0):

Setting SparkContext did not work for me, I had to set it in spark_session.

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate() # version 3.1.1-amzn-0
conf = sc.getConf()
#NO#NO#NO#NO#NO#NO#NO#NO#NO#NO setting SparkContext does not work. 
# conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "LEGACY") # SPARK-31404   NOPE

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

#YES#YES#YES#YES#YES#YES#YES#YES#YES#YES#YES setting spark_session does work. 
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "LEGACY") #SPARK-31404
print(spark.conf.get("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite")) #see?
```

This may depend on how you are using sc & spark, I was querying with:

```
df = spark.read.format("xml").etc
```