# Pyspark - iterate on a big dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I'm using the following code

```
    events_df = []
    for i in df.collect():
        v = generate_event(i)
        events_df.append(v)
  
    events_df = spark.createDataFrame(events_df, schema)
```

to go over each dataframe item and add an event header calculated in the `generate_event` function

```
def generate_event(delta_row):
    
    header = {
        "id": 1,
        ...
    }

    row = Row(Data=delta_row)
    return EntityEvent(header, row)


class EntityEvent:
    def __init__(self, _header, _payload):
        self.header = _header
        self.payload = _payload
```

It works fine locally for `df` with few items (even with 1 000 000 items) but when we have more than **6 millions** the  **aws glue job** fail

Note: with `rdd` seems to be better but I can't use it because I've a problem with dates < 1900-01-01 ([issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72211859/pyspark-glue-3-0-issue-upgrading-of-spark-3-0-reading-dates-before-1582-10))

is there a way to chunk the dataframe and consolidate at the end ?

Comment: what does `generate_event()` do exactly? there might be an easier way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that we can preview is to use spark promise features, like adding new columns using [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.struct.html?highlight=struct) and [`create_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.struct.html?highlight=struct) functions...

```
events_df = (
        df
        .withColumn(
            "header",
            f.create_map(
                f.lit("id"),
                f.lit(1)
            )
        )
...
```

So we can create columns as much as we need and make transformations to get the required header structure

PS: this solution (add new columns to the dataframe rather than iterate on it) avoid using `rdd` and brings a big advantage in terms of performance !